# how to add a list in the next row to a CSV that already has contents in c#

Tags: c#, csv

how to add a list in the next row to a CSV that already has contents in c#

```
List1 = 3 3 3 3 3 3 6 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 5 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 0 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2
List2 =  3 3 5 5 7 7 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 6 7 7 7 7 7 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2
```

my code like this

```
public void ExportCsvChain(List<DataChain> genericList)
{
    Debug.Log("masuk export csv");
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    string _path = null;
    if (_path == null) _path = "C:/Users/";
    string fileName = _path + "/FOLDER/alif2"; 
    //var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    //var finalPath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName + ".csv");
    var finalPath = Path.Combine(fileName + ".csv");
    if (!File.Exists(finalPath))
    {
        var file = File.Create(finalPath);
        file.Close();
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(finalPath, true);
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
    }
    foreach (DataChain obj in genericList)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        var line = obj.x;
        sb.Append(line.ToString() + ',');

        //sb.AppendLine(line);
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(finalPath, true);
        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

csv:

[image: csv]

what i want is like this

[image: what i want is like this]

Comment: May be you should read [System.IO.File.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DFR-FR%26k%3Dk(System.IO.File.AppendAllLines)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Add a linebreak at the proper spot in the loop `sb.AppendLine();`. And then don't trust what you see in Excel. For example Excel uses the system settings separator char here. In many cultures that is not a comma but a semikolon or even something complete different. Check the format with a plain text editor. CSV is just plain text.